# How to toogle two Field in SSRS?

Tags: reporting-services

I would like to use the toogle field for two things.

(1) Open the Detail list
(2) Make the header title visible

**If someone take the toogle plus sign THEN the details should open AND the text on the header line title should also be visible.**

Is this possible to do?

**From this:**
[image: From this]

**To this:**
[image]